# Login check php restrictions

Tags: php, session, authentication

i'm working with php and I have a page where users loggin and i'm trying to put the restriction on the homepage so you can't acess it by URL. The session in the login is being made successfully but I cant put the restriction working.

Here is my login:

```
<?php
//short_open_tag = true;
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    if($_POST)
   {

$host="xxxx"; // Host name 
$username="xxxx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xxxxx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xxxx"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="utilizador";


// Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($link , $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");


    $tbl_name="utilizador"; // Table name 

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST['username']);
    $encrypted_password = mysqli_real_escape_string( $link , $_POST['password']);
    $sql="SELECT nome FROM $tbl_name WHERE nome='$username' and  pass='$encrypted_password'";
    $encrypted_password = md5($encrypted_password);
    $result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    // If result = 1 then login success
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $username1 = $_SESSION['user']; 

        header("Location: homepage.php");

    }
    else {
        header("Location: index2.php");

        die;
    } 
}
if (!(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ''))
 {

    header ("Location: homepage.php");
}


  $link->close();
  ?>
```

And this is my Login Check on the homepage:

```
    // Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// CHECK LOG IN
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['user'][0] . "!";
     $username1 = $_SESSION['user']; 

    setType($username1, "string");
    var_dump($username1);
 } else {
echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
// END OF LOG IN CHECK


 ?>
```

What seems to be wrong with the code? Since the login is being made..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are mixing mysql_* library with mysqli which is really bad! You should use one or another, preferable mysqli. The way you are right now it wouldn't take much for you to mistakenly use the wrong library on the wrong connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to get session into a variable unless you use it later. But anyway , if you see "Please log in first to see this page." on the page you dont wanna show, then put    `header('Location: ../yourLogInPage.php');`

Answer (score 0):

I was once told that `session_start` should always be at the top of your document. I doubt that is the reason for this problem though.

Some things to think of when having problems with sessions.

- Was the session initilated on the same domain? A session started at http://www.yourhost.com does not necesarily work (depending on server configuration) on http://yourhost.com. There are work arounds for this so that session variables can be interpreted through different sub domains as well. Have a look at `session_set_cookie_params()`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php
- `session_start()` should be at top of your page. If you include a page in a php document it's not necesary (in fact, that will create a notice) to set it again. However, in an external document that you communicate with through, for example AJAX then it is necessary to declare session_start again.
- Make sure that you have identified the actual problem, not taking for granted that it's the sessions variables or your logic that is wrong. You might have a syntax error elsewhere that causes problems.

In your case I would defientely try to echo out the session variables in the page where you do your check to make sure they are recognized and that they hold the values that you expect them to hold.

As mentioned by Prix. Stick to one MySQL library (and refrain from the mysql native functions as they are deprecated). Your choise of mysqli is great, even though I personally prefer PDO. http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

`$_SESSION("user")[0]` vs `$_SESSION("user")`